# android mediaplayer: how to get player status except isPlaying?

Tags: android, media-player

mediaplayer has isPlaying,but only this. How can I know player is isPaused or isStopped ?

> Playback can be paused and stopped, and the current playback position
>   can be adjusted. Playback can be paused via pause(). When the call to
>   pause() returns, the MediaPlayer object enters the Paused state. Note
>   that the transition from the Started state to the Paused state and
>   vice versa happens asynchronously in the player engine. It may take
>   some time before the state is updated in calls to isPlaying(), and it
>   can be a number of seconds in the case of streamed content. from:
>   [MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

All the methods you saw are the only ones that are available. For other things, you can use:

```
try {
  //command
} finally {
  //only called once the calls in the try clause are completed
}
```

Comment: even I not call isPlaying at better? because its status has seconds delay.

Comment: Look through the Listeners. That might help

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no method available in [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) API to get the current status other than playing or not.

[MediaPlayer.isPlaying()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29) method returns true if currently playing, false otherwise and may throw IllegalStateException if called in invalid state.

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
 // MediaPlayer is in play state
}
else{
 // MediaPlayer is not in play state 
}
```

I recommend you to keep an enum flag to identify each state, for example

```
public enum PlayerStates{PAUSED,STOPPED,PLAYING};
PlayerStates state;
...

public void pause(){
mPlayer.pause();
state=PlayerStates.PAUSED;
}

public void play(){
mPlayer.start();
state=PlayerStates.PLAYING;
}

public void stop(){
mPlayer.stop();
state=PlayerStates.STOPPED;
}


// returns the current state of MediaPlayer
public PlayerStates getState(){
    return state;
}
```

I hope this helps you in someway.